# Separate DNA fragments with very different size (oligo and lambda-DNA)

Tags: dna, purification, ligation

I am running a ligation reaction to one of the sticky ends of lambda-DNA.

The oligo for the ligation is 25 bp (10x excess), whereas lambda-DNA is 48 kbp. I would like to recover the lambda-DNA and discard the unreacted excess oligo.
Given their vastly different molecular weights, they should be easy to separate, but I could not find a standard methodology online.

I do not want to run gel and my total sample volume is 0.5 mL. There are some filtration columns that may [work](https://www.gelifesciences.com/en/us/shop/molecular-biology/purification/gel-filtration-columns/illustra-microspin-g-50-columns-p-00056#related-documents), but the input volume is only 25 uL (I have 20 times that).

I don't have to get rid of *all* the oligo, having slightly more lambda-DNA than oligo at the end would suffice.

Which simple protocol may work in this case?

Answer (score 1):

A spin column might work for your purposes since you can do multiple rounds of binding if your volume is too large to bind in a single pass, but for DNA of that size a lot will be irreversibly stuck to the column.  See for example [the protocol](https://www.neb.com/protocols/2015/11/23/monarch-pcr-and-dna-cleanup-kit-protocol) for the [Monarch® PCR & DNA Cleanup Kit](https://www.neb.com/products/t1030-monarch-pcr-dna-cleanup-kit-5-ug#Product%20Information).

Consequently I would recommend just doing an [ethanol precipitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol_precipitation), which favors recovery of longer DNA molecules (see for example [this protocol](http://barricklab.org/twiki/bin/view/Lab/ProtocolsEthanolPrecipitation)).

Comment: Nice answer. The Monarch stuff only seems to work for [DNA up to 25 kpb](https://international.neb.com/products/t1030-monarch-pcr-dna-cleanup-kit-5-ug#Product%20Information) (may not work for my 48 kbp). My lambda-DNA didn't seem to go trough the gel filtration column, I may take a look into that ethanol precipitation.